# Rails 3 - Conditional Routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a routing question about rails 3, and setting up a conditional :root path.

Right now, my route.rb has the following:

```
root :to => "topics#index"
```

This is great and dandy, but only if a user is on their specific subdomain (basecamp style) on my site. If they go to www.myapp.com or myapp.com, this should not be the same :root. I was wonder if this was at all possible to setup, something that would be like...

```
if default_subdomain(www, "")
root :to => "promos#index"
else
root :to => "topics#index
end
```

I know this wouldn't be allowed in the routes.rb, but something that would do the same logical thing. Does anyone have any experience with this, or any documentation/blog that I could read over to try to set something like this up.

Thanks

Per chuck's help below(thanks a ton), this ended up being my working code:

```
constraints(:subdomain => "www") do
  root :to => "promos#index"
  end

  root :to => "topics#index"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `:requirements` tag to accomplish this.

```
root :to => "promos#index", :requirements => { :subdomain => "www" }
root :to => "topics#index"
```

I think this will work. I've never encountered it going by sub-domain/lack of a subdomain.

**Edit**: After doing some reading, Rails 3 uses `:constraints` instead.

Comment: Is there some way to list as a constraint that the param 'email' must exist? As in `/url.com?email=emailaddress`, and to route one way if email exists and another if it doesn't?